# What value to set the baud rate to

Tags: serial-port, baud-rate

In [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), I am establishing a serial link to an Arduino. Is a higher baud rate always better? I am using [9,600 baud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Settings) now, but that is merely because it is the most standard value.

Comment: Presumably, the serial connection is over USB (the normal USB connection to the Arduino). Or is a separate USB-to-serial adapter involved?

Comment: @PeterMortensen direct via USB. Thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have better luck over at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/.

> > **Why do people settle?**
>
> People settle because it is more than fast enough. The most common use is just to print some stuff on a terminal
>   for debuggin. 9600 baud is 960 characters per second, or 12 x 80
>   character lines per second. How fast can you read? :)
>
> If your program is using the serial port for bulk data transfer, you
>   would choose not to settle.

See the following resources:

- [Serial.begin(): Why not always use 28800?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4071/serial-begin-why-not-always-use-28800/4079#4079)
- [How high of a baud rate can I go (without errors)?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/296/how-high-of-a-baud-rate-can-i-go-without-errors)

Answer (score 3):

Good question. I've spent years working with modems and I'm not stranger to baud rates. My Arduino uses a USB connection and it handles the baud rate, so I never got into messing with it.

It's strictly how quickly do you want your program loaded. It has no other effect. It would be reasonable to consider that low-end equipment might not support the higher end speed. From the communications perspective, the higher the baud rate the more chance of data errors. I think it's a stretch to think the communications between the pc and an Arduino is going to have much of an issue.

Comment: Dear CubeRoot. I didn't try faster rates as I'm writing minimal amounts of data. Your answer is great, as I now understand that 9600 should be OK. Thank you.